# Usage of "SHOULD BE"

Tags: grammar

> Wearing swimsuit should be mandatory.

Can this be used as an instruction?

I suggest

> Wearing swimsuit is mandatory.

But I want to prove why "should be" is not correct in this sentence. Can someone help??

Comment: Look up the meaning of "should" in any online dictionary, include the links and then explain why you think "should" can be omitted IN your question.

Comment: What do you mean by *instruction*? A spoken command to a person, or text on a sign, or part of a list setting out the procedure for doing something? (Instruction doesn't necessarily mean something that's mandatory, e.g. the instructions on a shampoo bottle or with flat pack furniture.)

Comment: This sentence is to be printed on a board kept near a swimming pool

Answer (score 1):

Saying "wearing a swim suit **is** mandatory" is conveying an existing policy.

Saying "wearing a swim suit **should be** mandatory" is making a recommendation about policy.

Both are valid expressions - the meaning is different.

Comment: Yes, *mandatory* is an order, *must* is an order, and *should* is a suggestion, an opinion that is open for ignoring.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: Indeed, if someone is saying that wearing a swim suit _should be_ mandatory, it's quite likely to be the case that it currently _isn't_ :)